# how to calculate font size for various resolution?

Tags: android

Am trying to write generic code for all the resolutions. Being a new developer am getting stopped by this font issue. Consider am having various resolutions ( 100 * 100, 200 * 200, 300 * 300 etc ).Am having a textview if suppose i set the font size as 20 for 100*100, when i am porting this code to 200*200, the size of the font seems to be very small for the resolution 200*200. Could any plz tell how to calculate font size for various regions. Is there any formual available to calculate it.. plz advise.. thanks in advance...

Comment: just set the textsize in dip and it will maange itself according to screen resolution

Comment: have to say that I'm not an Android developer, but: If you use some values for different resolutions, you can multiply your font size by the number you set. For instance value=1 for the resolution 100, value=1.4 for the resolution 200, value=1,6 for 300, etc. And when you set the font size you should multiply it by the value.

Answer (score 6):

Try using `sp` unit for your font size.

> **sp**
>
> Scale-independent Pixels - this is
> like the dp unit, but it is also
> scaled by the user's font size
> preference. It is recommend you use
> this unit when specifying font sizes,
> so they will be adjusted for both the
> screen density and user's preference.

More information [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Dimension)

Take sometime reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2025282/difference-of-px-dp-dip-and-sp-in-android) to understand the different measurement units used in Andriod as well.